# reading xml in c# and returning edited transaction

Tags: c#, xml

I used the functionality in VS to create a class that defines my input transaction. The code is a socket service that reads in an XML transaction. I need to change the information on the transaction and return it. There is a RESULT node that can occur x number of times per transaction, so I need to iterate through those. My problem is I don't know how to access the information to replace it. There are 3 different group node within the RESULT node, and the auto-generated class defined it as follows.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class RATE_SHOPRESULT
{
    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("COMMON", typeof(RATE_SHOPRESULTCOMMON))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PACKAGE", typeof(RATE_SHOPRESULTPACKAGE))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SERVICE", typeof(string))]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

To get down to this I can instantiate `transaction.RESULTS[0].Items[0]` but how to I define the type after that? The service defines what I need to change, and the individual data that needs to be changed is either in the common or package group depending upon the service.

Here is an example of the XML:

> ```
> <RATE_SHOP>
>   <COMPANY_CODE>XXX</COMPANY_CODE>
>   <RESULTS>
>     <RESULT>
>       <COMMON>
>         <BASE>15.91</BASE>
>         <SPECIAL>1.58</SPECIAL>
>         <DISCOUNT>5.14</DISCOUNT>
>         <TOTAL>12.35</TOTAL>
>         <BILLED_WEIGHT>20</BILLED_WEIGHT>
>         <SHIPPER>LOMO_GEORGIA</SHIPPER>
>         <ZONE>4</ZONE>
>         <FUEL_SURCHARGE>0.53</FUEL_SURCHARGE>
>       </COMMON>
>       <PACKAGE>
>         <OVERSIZE_INDICATOR>4</OVERSIZE_INDICATOR>
>       </PACKAGE>
>       <SERVICE>BWTI_FXRS.SP.SM</SERVICE>
>     </RESULT>
>   </RESULTS>
> </RATE_SHOP>
> ```

The `RATE_SHOPRESULT` class corresponds to the `<RESULT>` element.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't also an auto-generated property `public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName`?

Comment: Also, can you show the XSD (or XML) you used to auto-generate the code above?

Comment: There is no ItemsChoiceType. The XML transaction is too large, it won't let me post it.

Comment: I chopped off some of the results iterations. <RATE_SHOP>
<COMPANY_CODE>XXX</COMPANY_CODE>
<RESULTS>
                <RESULT><COMMON><BASE>15.91</BASE><SPECIAL>1.58</SPECIAL><DISCOUNT>5.14</DISCOUNT><TOTAL>12.35</TOTAL><BILLED_WEIGHT>20</BILLED_WEIGHT><SHIPPER>LOMO_GEORGIA</SHIPPER><ZONE>4</ZONE><FUEL_SURCHARGE>0.53</FUEL_SURCHARGE></COMMON><PACKAGE><OVERSIZE_INDICATOR>4</OVERSIZE_INDICATOR></PACKAGE><SERVICE>BWTI_FXRS.SP.SM</SERVICE></RESULT>
</RESULTS>
</RATE_SHOP>

Comment: There is only ever going to be one instance of RESULTS. Then, within each RESULT, there is only going to be one COMMON, one PACKAGE, and one SERVICE instance. Could I change the class to define one each of those within the Items object array?

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no XSD, the [XML-to-c# converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't know how many repetitions of the elements `<COMMON>`, `<PACKAGE>` and `<SERVICE>` might appear inside the `<RESULT>` element, and in what order.  Thus it auto-generates a polymorphic array of `object`, called `Item`, which might contain any number of the types corresponding to these elements.

However, as developers we might make the reasonable assumption that each `<RESULT>` element will contain *no more than one* of each sub-element.  In that case, you could manually define your `RATE_SHOPRESULT` as follows:

```
public partial class RATE_SHOPRESULT
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("COMMON")]
    public RATE_SHOPRESULTCOMMON Common { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PACKAGE")]
    public RATE_SHOPRESULTPACKAGE Package { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SERVICE")]
    public string Service { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to preserve the generality of the auto-defined classes, you would need to test the type of each entry in the array.  For instance, the following code and extension method filters the `Items` array for items of each type, returning the items and their array index:

```
public static class PolymorphicEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, TResult>> OfIndexAndType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return OfIndexAndTypeIterator<TResult>(source);
    }

    static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, TResult>> OfIndexAndTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (object obj in source)
        {
            if (obj is TResult) 
                yield return new KeyValuePair<int, TResult>(i, (TResult)obj);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
        var commons = transaction.RESULTS[0].Items.OfIndexAndType<RATE_SHOPRESULTCOMMON>();
        var packages = transaction.RESULTS[0].Items.OfIndexAndType<RATE_SHOPRESULTPACKAGE>();
        var services = transaction.RESULTS[0].Items.OfIndexAndType<string>();
```

Or, to initialize a new result, do something like:

```
        var result = new RATE_SHOPRESULT { Items = new object[] { new RATE_SHOPRESULTCOMMON { /* Fill in properties */ }, new RATE_SHOPRESULTPACKAGE { /* Fill in properties */ }, "service name" } };
```